# Open WPF window in outlook 2013/16 vsto extension

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, vsto

I want to show a wpf window on button click event

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{  
    ExampleWindow wpfwindow = new ExampleWindow();
    wpfwindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

But nothing happens on button click (and no breakpoint works, anywhere). But if I put `throw new NotImplementedException();` in the event handler it'll be executed. I also added the needed references to my project (including `WindowsFormsIntegration`).

A Visual Studio restart, Windows restart and complete rebuild don't help.

Comment: What if you change `private` to `public`?

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Remove the second argument from your handler as well. A `button` does not pass a `RibbonControlEventArgs` parameter.

Comment: Cant do this because it doesn't match the delegate RibbonControlEventHandler

Comment: Oh, looks like you're using the visual designer, apparently it's different. I might be barking up the wrong tree, sorry.